# Select item from one ComboBox and remove that item from other ComboBoxes

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

Im writing an QT application, where I have 3 QComboBoxes, with a list of values. I'm trying to do so, when I select one item in a QComboBox, I will remove it from the other QComboBoxes, and when I select another or nothing, it will reappear in the other QComboBoxes again.

Do you have any ideas for this?

Edit:
I have tried to use QStringList, where I had a slot, which removed it from the other QComboBoxes, but it was very bugged and often inserted 2 whitespaces and the same drink twice.

Comment: Do all comboboxes have the same items?

Comment: When nothing is selected, yes. But for example when one item is selected in ComboBox1, it will be removed from ComboBox2 and ComboBox3.

Answer (score 0):

If all comboboxes contain the same items, then you can use the current index of one combobox to disable and hide that index of other comboboxes.

You can just subclass `QComboBox` and create a slot like this:

```
void MyComboBox::disableItem(int index)
{
    QListView *list_view = qobject_cast<QListView*>(view());
    if(list_view)
    {
        QStandardItemModel *model =  qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(list_view->model());   
        list_view->setRowHidden(index, true);
        if(model)
        {
            model->item(index, 0)->setEnabled(false);
        }   
    }
}
```

Then you just connect the [`QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) signal from other comboboxes to this slot. Do this for all 3 comboboxes.

You should also create a logic for enabling and showing the items again when they shouldn't be disabled. It's almost the same function as the one above. You could just create a list of indexes that should be hidden for that combobox and use that to show all the other indexes.

Comment: So I tried your solution and when I change the index of one of the ComboBoxes, it crashes. I used some qDebug messages and found out the crashes happen when I try to cast ListView. First I couldn't compile and got the error "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments" and then thought the () after view was a mistake, so I tried removing them, but then it crashes. I tried changing view to QObject::sender(), but this makes it crash on QStandardItemModel conversion.

Comment: @Thisen [`QComboBox::view`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#view) is a public function of `QComboBox` class. Try renaming the local variable `QListView view`  to something else, like `QListView list_view`.